# How to create inward shadow(bevel effect) in container,

Tags: flutter, containers

**How to achieve something like this:**

[image]

This is my code:

```
                        Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width- 
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*1/7,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              border: Border.all(color: OpimaAppTheme.buttonColor,width: 3),
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    offset: Offset(2, 2),
                                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                                    color: OpimaAppTheme.buttonShadowColor),
                                BoxShadow(
                                    offset: Offset(-0, 0),
                                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                                    color: OpimaAppTheme.buttonShadowColor),

                              ],

                            ),
                          )
```

This only gives me an elevation effect i.e either outward shadow or no shadow, I've tried with all the different combinations of offset values. I don't want to use any Neumorphic Package.

Comment: Check out [Flutter Neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic)

Comment: this article may help https://medium.com/flutter-community/neumorphic-designs-in-flutter-eab9a4de2059